# python3 ValueError: shapes (4,1) and (4,3) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning

I'm write a Planar data classification program with one hidden layer from a Coursera course.

What should this code do and why doesn't it work?

```
def backward_propagation(parameters, cache, X, Y):
    """
    Implement the backward propagation using the instructions above.

    """
    m = X.shape[1]

    # First, retrieve W1 and W2 from the dictionary "parameters".
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
    W1 = parameters["W1"]
    W2 = parameters["W2"]
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # Retrieve also A1 and A2 from dictionary "cache".
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
    A1 = cache["A1"]
    A2 = cache["A1"]
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # Backward propagation: calculate dW1, db1, dW2, db2. 
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 6 lines of code, corresponding to 6 equations on slide above)
    dZ2= A2-Y
    dW2 = (1/m)*np.dot(dZ2,A1.T)
    db2 = (1/m)*np.sum(dZ2, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    dZ1 = np.multiply(np.dot(W2.T, dZ2),1 - np.power(A1, 2))
    dW1 = (1 / m) * np.dot(dZ1, X.T)
    db1 = (1/m)*np.sum(dZ1,axis1,keepdims=True)
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    grads = {"dW1": dW1,
             "db1": db1,
             "dW2": dW2,
             "db2": db2}

    return grads
    parameters, cache, X_assess, Y_assess =      backward_propagation_test_case()

    grads = backward_propagation(parameters, cache, X_assess, Y_assess)
    print ("dW1 = "+ str(grads["dW1"]))
    print ("db1 = "+ str(grads["db1"]))
    print ("dW2 = "+ str(grads["dW2"]))
    print ("db2 = "+ str(grads["db2"]))
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
ValueError: shapes (4,1) and (4,3) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)
```

Comment: Please post error with complete log for clarity. But this is mostly because of some of the np.dot method, your dimensions are not matching while matrix multiplication. Checking dimensions with ```assert``` always helps.

Answer (score 5):

When multiplying two matrices i.e., np.dot. The column of the first matrix and the row of the second matrix should be equal. That's what numpy is throwing error. You can't multiply a 4x1 matrix with a 4x3 matrix.

Comment: Thank you! Do you knew how  to change two  matrix to the same size?

Comment: Check whether your previous calculations are correct. And if so, you can make a transpose by A.T where A is your matrix. But don't take transpose of both the matrices unless your calculations need so.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized `A2=cache["A1"]` but it should be `A2=cache["A2"]`.

Answer (score 0):

try re oreder your metrices
your code:

```
dW1 = (1 / m) * np.dot(dZ1, X.T)
```

try this code:

```
enter code here
dW1 = (1 / m) * np.dot( X.T,dZ1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `dZ1 = np.multiply(np.dot(W2.T, dZ2),1` with `dZ1 = np.multiply(np.dot(W2.T, dZ2),1)` ,i.e, add closing bracket at the end for np.multiply . And also replace `A2=cache["A1"]` with `A2=cache["A2"]`